# Div mouse hover issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to show my `text` class when I hover the img and hide them when user mouseout the `div` instead of `img`.

With the following codes, the text class is hidden as soon as mouse out of img. Can anyone help me about it? Thanks a lot.

My code:

**HTML**

```
<div id='container'>
    <div class='imgDiv'>
        <img src='a.jpg' />
        <br>
        <p class='text'> picutre text!!! </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.imgDiv{
    height:500px; //way higher than the image
}
```

**jQuery**

```
//I want to show text only when mouse hover to img
$('#container').on('mouseover','img',function(){                 
    $(this).closest('div').css('background-color','grey');
        $(this).parent().siblings('.text').fadeIn('fast');
    });

//I want to hide text when mouse out of imgDiv but it doesn't work with my following codes
//the text will be hidden right after mouse out of image
$('#container').on('mouseout','.imgDiv',function(){
    //hide text
    $(this).children('.text').fadeOut('fast');             
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use CSS?

```
.imgDiv p {display:none}
.imgDiv:hover p {display:block}
```

Answer (score 2):

Do it the clean way, give the image a class, like text_trigger and use that instead.

```
$('.text_trigger').hover(function() {                 

   $(this).closest('div').css('background-color','grey');
   $(this).parent().siblings('.text').fadeIn('fast');
}, function() {
  $(this).parent().siblings('.text').fadeOut('fast');
});
```

Comment: I need to use 'on' because my pictures are ajax generated. callback function doesn't seem to work. Also, I want the text disappears after mouseout my div, not image.

Comment: So use live instead: $('.text_trigger').live('hover', function().... Live will work for any .text_trigger image added later

Comment: Re the callback now working, probably b/c parent().siblings('.text') is incorrect. If the text is the next element after the image, as it seems to be, just use .next()